# RabbitMQ in Docker container doesn't allow my Java app to connect

Tags: java, docker, rabbitmq

I am running RabbitMQ in the Docker container. In addition to RabbitMQ image I also installed RabbitMQ management plugin.

Using plugin I created user 'executor'. I set user permissions to

```
 
Virtual host / 
Configure regexp    .* 
Write regexp    .* 
Read regexp     .*
```

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] argv)  throws Exception {
     String message;
     ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
     factory.setHost(SERVER);
     factory.setUsername(RABBIT_USER);
     factory.setPassword(RABBIT_USER_PASSWORD);
     Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
     Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
     channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, IS_DURABLE_QUEUE, false, false, null);

     message = argv.length==1?argv[0]:"Hello World!";
     channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
     System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
     channel.close();
     connection.close();
}
```

When I run this app I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:362)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:134)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:997)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:956)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:914)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1068)
    at ca.meh.hial.producer.Producer.main(Producer.java:24)
```

Clearly user can't connect due to authentication issues.

I am not sure if I need to install some other plugin. Or do I need to configure Docker container to validate credentials?

Comment: What does the rabbit logs say? From the error message it looks like you need to connect via SSL or some other encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't use management console from one Docker container to manage RabbitMQ in another Docker container.